# Sending email using ASP.Net without revealing my password in the code

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, webforms, passwords

My form looks like this:[image]

and when the send button is clicked the following code is invoked:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Command-line argument must be the SMTP host.
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        // Specify the email sender.
        // Create a mailing address that includes a UTF8 character
        // in the display name.
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(txtEmail.ToString().Trim(),
        txtName.ToString() + (char)0xD8,
        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        // Set destinations for the email message.
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("nyamathulani@gmail.com");
        // Specify the message content.
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Body = txtMsg.ToString();
        // Include some non-ASCII characters in body and subject.
        string someArrows = new string(new char[] { '\u2190', '\u2191', '\u2192', '\u2193' });
        message.Body += Environment.NewLine + someArrows;
        message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Subject = txtSubject.ToString() + someArrows;
        message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        // Set the method that is called back when the send operation ends.
        client.SendCompleted += new
        SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
        // The userState can be any object that allows your callback
        // method to identify this send operation.
        // The userToken is a string constant.
        string userState = "Thulani awaits your message";
        client.SendAsync(message, userState);
        btnSend.Text = "Sending...";

        // Clean up.
        message.Dispose();
    }
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTE4j.png)I want to be able to send an email from an ASP.NET web form without using my password in the code as I am building a portfolio website and need to use my personal email address

Comment: How is your application hosted? On prem? Azure? AWS? Go Daddy? Some other hosting?

Comment: Currently on a local server intending to host on either Github-pages or Azure

Comment: Using Azure, your best bet is to use Server-Side Email-Sending and have your credentials in a KeyVault. I'd also recommend to use an email account dedicated to this application.

Comment: @Fildor, thanks will update you if this solves my issue

Comment: BTW, if it's just a "get in contact" form, you absolutely can make that a static Web Page with a form and send data to one of the various "Html Form To Email" providers out there, if this is all it is to this.

Comment: @Fildor... It can't be static cause I have included a custom dynamic google maps with animations

Answer (score -3):

I think anyway you have to input your password either in the code or you have to manually design, to enter the password at the time of sending the email.

Comment: No, this doesn't have to be done and should *not* be done. If you're unfamiliar with the different options for securing configuration data, it's best not to answer and instead leave the question to others who are more familiar with this.

Comment: @Krishna I have updated my question to show you what I'm trying to achieve, and your suggestion is not a solution as end-users must not use my email and password to send me an email

Comment: @mason are you familiar with this technique

Comment: @ThulaniNyama Yes. Your best bet is to follow Fildor's suggestion.

Comment: ^^ If you chose to use Azure, that is. But on other Cloud Platforms, there surely are similar concepts to protect application secrets.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).